# How to get image from Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, amazon-s3

How to get images from Amazon S3 Bucket? I have added some images  into amazon S3 bucket now i want to retrive those images. How can i retrive it from bucket & show All list on page?? I'm using C#,Asp.net MVC3

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the S3 admin UI, you should be able to select a file and it will show you the URL.  Then just use that URL in your code.

Comment: I have the url,can you give me a code snippet thanks

Comment: are you just including it in an ASP.NET page?  If so, just use an <img> tag with that url.  If that's not what you need, please give more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you very much, i'm just use <img src=url/> and its work,